# Tooltip over small image

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am currently about to setup our forum and already made a verification system, but wondering how to make a tooltip just like Facebook have. Once you mouse over the check image, you will see some sort of text.

I already tried some way to achieve it but did not work.

[GoDaddy's Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/uk.GoDaddy/?brand_redir=8749090685)

**HTML**

*The img tag contains these:*

```
data="BroHosting confirmed that this profile is an authentic for person, media, brand or company." class="tip"
```

**CSS /Style**

```
img:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

img[data]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5px ;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Do you have a possible fix or other idea or suggestion maybe?

Comment: What actually do you expect?

Comment: view the facebook page, that I listed here and mouse over to the blue check.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Why not use bootstrap tooltip?https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: You can either use bootstrap tooltips,"https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp" or opentips "https://jsfiddle.net/Hema_Nandagopal/671ptukx/2/"

Comment: By the way, you can do a basic, non-styled tooltip by putting text in a `title` attribute of almost any element. That type of tooltip will only display after the mouse hovers over the element without moving for a moment, which you probably don't want in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.check {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #5890ff;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.check:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.check:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="check" data-tooltip="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"></a>
```

Comment: I have to do this for image not for an <a> tag. :( with img not working.

Comment: Oh, I had to just put image between <a> tag, thank you!